# how to insert image urls from google cloud storage into this json file using python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I am using colab to get the images from GCP buckets (inputs) to insert the buckets' images url into this b.json file (output) .

I have a b.json file that is like this:
[image]

How do i add the image urls into the highlighted portion of the code?

the image urls are from Google cloud storage, where the folders are categorised into district/street/blk no

```
this is the code used to extract the images from google cloud storage:
import json
from google.cloud import storage

client=storage.Client()
bucket=client.bucket('appspot.com')
blobs =bucket.list_blobs(prefix='district/street/blk_no')

with open("b.json",'r') as f:
    data=json.load(f)

for blob in blobs:
    url=blob.public_url
    id=blob.name.split("/")[1]
    name=id.upper()
    street=blob.name.split("/")[2]
    blk_no=blob.name.split("/")[3]
    blk_id=blk_no.split("/")[0]
    max_floor=blk_no.split("/")[1]
    year_completed=blk_no.split("/")[2]
    blk_name=blk_no.split("/")[3]
    rent_units=blk_no.split("/")[4]
    buy_units=blk_no.split("/")[5]

    if id not in data:
        data[id]= {
            "id":id,
            "name":name,
            "images":[url],
            "streets":{
                street:{
                  "blks":{
                      blk_id:{
                          "id":blk_id,
                          "max_floor":max_floor,
                          "year_completed":year_completed,
                          "name":blk_name,
                          "images":[url],
                          "rent_units": rent_units,
                          "buy_units": buy_units
                      }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    else: 
            if street not in data[id]["streets"]:
                data[id]["streets"][street]={
                    "blks":{
                        blk_id:{
                              "id":blk_id,
                              "max_floor":max_floor,
                               "year_completed":year_completed,
                               "name":blk_name,
                               "images":[url],
                               "rent_units": rent_units,
                               "buy_units": buy_units                    
                        }
                    }
                } 
  else:
              if blk_id not in data[id]["streets"][street]["blks"]:
                      data[id]["streets"][street]["blks"][blk_id]={
                                  "id":blk_id,
                                  "max_floor":max_floor,
                                  "year_completed":year_completed
                    }
```

been struck for a few weeks, any help would be greatly appreciated  :)

Comment: Hi `Dom` . I am just suggesting a workaround, you can get the [signed urls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually) for your gcs bucket objects using the python code output the data to csv file and convert your data from [csv to json](https://pythonexamples.org/python-csv-to-json/). I hope this might work for you

Comment: can you revert back if this has helped you in solving your issue